# Game won't update: difference between Play Store and manual Install ? (Plants vs Zombies 2)

Tags: backup, uninstallation

my "Plants vs Zombies 2" won't update (it never did).

I wonder if the reason is that, for the rush to have the game, I probably installed it manually downloading it from the internet.

BUT, Play Store says the game is already installed, and won't update it.

Do I have to manually remove it and then install it ?
How do I have to backup my savegame ?

Comment: How do you know there's an update?  I accidentally bought Angry Birds on both the Play Store and the Amazon App Store, and the former will happily overwrite the version from the latter when there is an update.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have to remove it, then reinstall it from the Playstore. It will probably see the installed file on the phone, but your Playstore account doesn't know about this, and won't activate the update.

You can use Titanium Backup to backup the game, if your phone is rooted. Titanium Backup can backup apps and their data, and restore either of them separately. If the phone is not rooted, I don't know how to do this if the app doesn't have an export function.

But... probably it won't overwrite your personal data. I can't give you any guarantees, but you probably won't lose your personal settings.

Comment: Titanium Backup also has a feature to attach or detach apps from the Play Store.

Comment: @MatthewRead that doesn't work anymore. Play now always scans all installed packages and re-links them – even if installed from "other sources". I didn't check however what happens on a signature mismatch (e.g. packages from F-Droid use their own signatures), maybe those are left alone – which might explain the case, and approve the path recommended by this answer.

Comment: thank you very much. Sadly I'm not rooted, do you have any suggestions to backup my PvsZ2 savegames before I go on with the suggestion to remove - reinstall the game ?

Comment: No suggestions. It's a gamble. Your settings probably won't be overwritten.

Comment: If your device isn't rooted, but runs Android 4.0 or higher, there's also [Helium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.koushikdutta.backup) you could use to backup (and later restore) the app and its data. By default, *Helium* only backs up data – so if you do that, then uninstall the app, re-install it from Play, in a final step you might be able to simply restore the data and be done.

Comment: @Izzy Play doesn't re-link apps that have different signatures. Apps installed from Amazon or F-Droid contain different signatures, and if the OP downloaded a non-official version, it definitely wouldn't have the correct signature either.

Comment: If you uninstall the app, you will lose all your game data (unless you can back it up with some utility). And you can't update/install from the Play Store because Android doesn't allow updates when the signatures don't match. The only option is to uninstall the original and install directly from the Play Store.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger Apps on Aptoide often have the same signature as those on Play. Same applies to `.apk` files a dev might send you by mail (I know that, got some that way for testing quite often in the past). So since they've got the same signature, you're premise no longer holds – thus they get "linked" again.